# How to read the index of a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this:

```
> aaa
           AdjClose
2012-01-03   15.5
2012-01-04   18.8
2012-01-05   13.9
```

Doing `dt$AdjClose` I get get the "column" with the prices, but, how to get the dates ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rownames(aaa)` will give them to you. Do note that they will be a character vector, not something R considers dates. For that you need to convert the characters to dates using `as.Date()`. This is illustrated below:

```
> aaa
           AdjClose
2012-01-03     15.5
2012-01-04     18.8
2012-01-05     13.9
> rownames(aaa)
[1] "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05"
> class(rownames(aaa))
[1] "character"
> as.Date(rownames(aaa))
[1] "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05"
> class(as.Date(rownames(aaa)))
[1] "Date"
```

I didn't need to specify a `format` for the `as.Date()` call as your characters are already in the default format.

Comment: To add to Gavin's answer, I generally think it's a bad idea to store important information in row names as they could be lost with certain class changes etc.  IMHO it would be a good idea to store them as a column vector, something like `data.frame(date = rownames(aaa), aaa$AdjClose`